# Regex Js must have 1 alphabet and 1 character

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

the following is my regex

`regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+-.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*-[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+$/`

the overall rules is: alphabet-alphanumeric-number-alphabet-number

im having problem at `.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*`

the expected output for it to get a successful result for the alphanumeric part is

1. abc123
2. 123abc
3. 1abc23
4. ab23ca

and fail if

1. abcde
2. 12345

but the result i get is all successful include the expected fail result

1. abc-abc-123-abc-123
2. abc-123-123-abc-123

i see that using lookahead will also get the input after the dash(-) of the alphanumeric that caused it to be successful although it is not the expected result

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-(?![a-zA-Z]+-|\d+-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-\d+-[a-zA-Z]+-\d+$
```

It uses this negative lookahead to check the second subsequence is not only made by alphabets or numerics

```
(?![a-zA-Z]+-|\d+-)
```

Alternatively, you can use this positive lookahead to check the second subsequence is made by a digit preceded any alphabets or the other way around

```
(?=[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])
```

It is important to use a lookahead to check it right at the start of the subsequence, and do not use `.*` in this situation since it might consume a `-` and checks the wrong sequence behind it.

You may check the test result [here](https://regex101.com/r/LrAAgF/1)

Answer (score 1):

For the alphanumeric part, you can assert not only digits till the next hyphen.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
^[a-z]+-(?!\d+-)[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*-\d+-[a-z]+-\d+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]+-` Match 1+ chars a-z and `-`
- `(?!\d+-)` Negative lookahead, assert not only digits followed by `-`
- `[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*-` Match optional chars a-z, match a digit and optional chars a-z or a digit
- `\d+-[a-z]+-\d+` Match digits `-` chars a-z `-` digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GmIyRO/1)

```js
const regex = /^[a-z]+-(?!\d+-)[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*-\d+-[a-z]+-\d+$/i;
[
  "abc-abc-123-abc-123",
  "abc-123-123-abc-123",
  "abc-abcde-123-abc-123",
  "abc-12345-123-abc-123",
  "abc-ab23ca-123-abc-123",
  "abc-1abc23-123-abc-123"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
/([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+)/

-- or --

/[A-Za-z]/.test(val) && /[0-9]/.test(val)

var cases = [
    "abc123",
    "123abc",
    "1abc23",
    "ab23ca",
    // fail
    "abcde",
    "12345",
    "abc-abc-123-abc-123", // not clear if these should fail?
    "abc-123-123-abc-123"
];

cases.forEach(val => {
    var ok = /([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+)/.test(val)
    //var ok = /[A-Za-z]/.test(val) && /[0-9]/.test(val);
    console.log(val, ok);
});
```

Comment: But how do you incorporate it in the entire regex check? It only matches `abc123` and `123abc`. What about `1abc23` or `ab23ca`, or `ab12cd34ef56gh`? 